# Multiple onPress event on a single image component in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this picture, and I want to have multiple `onPress` event for this image.

Example if I touch the head part it will call the function `pressHead()` and if I touch the chest part it will call the function `pressChest()`.

[image]

So far I have tried plotting checkboxes on each part.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Image, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements';

export default class Screen extends Component {

  pressHead() {
    this.setState({checked1: !this.state.checked1})
    Alert.alert('Pressed Head', '');
  }

  pressChest() {
    this.setState({checked2: !this.state.checked2})
    Alert.alert('Pressed Chest', '');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{width: 200}}>
        <Image
          style={{width: 200, resizeMode: 'contain'}}
          source={require('../../assets/images/body-diagram.png')}
        />
        <CheckBox
          containerStyle={{position: 'absolute', top: 22, right: 75, padding: 0}}
          checkedIcon='dot-circle-o'
          uncheckedIcon='circle-o'
          checkedColor='#ff0000'
          checked={this.state.checked1}
          onPress={() => this.pressHead()}
        />
        <CheckBox
          containerStyle={{position: 'absolute', top: 70, right: 75, padding: 0}}
          checkedIcon='dot-circle-o'
          uncheckedIcon='circle-o'
          checkedColor='#ff0000'
          checked={this.state.checked1}
          onPress={() => this.pressChest()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

This does work. But if I try to use it on a larger device, the **position absolute** becomes not accurate enough.

Answer (score 0):

Give the constant height for the image and overlay the checkboxes as same above respect to image. Since height is also made constant you don't find any position issues of the checkbox in any screen.

Example :

```
<View style={{width: 200, height: 600}}>
    <Image
      style={{width: 200, height: 600 ,resizeMode: 'contain'}}
      source={require('../../assets/images/body-diagram.png')}
    />
```

Comment: Yes, that does work. But the width of 200 is okay on an iPhone X while it is so small on an iPad Pro (12.9) inch.

Comment: use percentages. make width to be 70% and height 70%. Know the head height percentage in that image like for suppose it is 10% then make checkbox style as style={{ width : "10%", height : "10%"}}

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by changing your image to `<ImageBackground  .. />` component after importing it from react-native.

After doing that you can place Touchable things inside of ImageBackground.

Example:

```
<ImageBackground source={require('../../assets/images/body-diagram.png')} style={{width: 200, height: 600, flexDirection: 'column'}}

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert('first pressed')}>
  <Text>First Area</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert('second pressed')}>
  <Text>Second Area</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert('third pressed')}>
  <Text>Third Area</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<ImageBackground/>
```